# How can I hide the on-screen buttons but keep the status bar

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, buttons, notification-bar

I have a Galaxy Nexus (rooted, if that helps) and I want to disable the on-screen buttons (back, home, apps), also called the [Navigation Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html#system-bars). Now there are plenty of apps (e.g. [Hide Bottom Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.hidebar)) that remove the buttons, but since they are based on killing some Android process (I believe), they also remove the Status Bar (on top of the screen).

Now I would like to keep the status bar, but *only* remove the on-screen buttons (because I would like to use gestures instead). Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://forums.miui.us/showthread.php?p=78420#post78420) - it's a matter of adding

```
qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
```

to `/system/build.prop` (root required).

Answer (score 1):

*Android 4.4 KitKat* has introduced *Immersive Full Screen Mode*. There's an app in the Play Store exploiting this feature: [Immersive Full-screen Mode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.immersivemode). It doesn't even need Root access.

Answer (score 0):

There are several roms with this feature baked into them [CM10.1](http://get.cm/?device=maguro&type=nightly) being one of them

But if you like the rom you currently have then I'd go with Stefan's answer